# Unable to locate a specific element using Xpath

Tags: xpath

I've created an xpath expression to locate the value of "Genre:" which is in this case "Drama". But, running my script I always get to the "Genre:". How to rectify my expression to locate "Drama"?

I've tried with:

```
//div[@class="mdif"]//li/b/text()
```

Elements within which the value is:

```
<div class="mdif">
<ul>
    <li><b>Genre:</b>Drama</li>
    <li><b>Quality:</b>1080p</li>
    <li><b>Screen:</b>1920x1080</li>
    <li><b>Size:</b>1.67G</li>
    <li><b>Rating:</b>6.1/10</li>
    <li><b>Peers:</b>17</li>
    <li><b>Seeds:</b>0</li>
</ul>
<a href="/movie/55000/download-lake-mungo-2008-1080p-mp4-yify-torrent.html" class="small button orange" target="_blank" title="Download Lake Mungo (2008) 1080p YIFY Torrent">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more accurate XPath than the currently accepted answer (works when `Genre` isn't in the first `li` and will only return the text() intended)...

```
//div[@class="mdif"]//li[b='Genre:']/text()
```

Comment: This is the very answer I was after. I wish i could have you earlier. Your answer saves the hardcoding and brings the result irrespective of it's position. thanks.

Comment: @SMth80 - Glad I could help. You can always change which answer is the accepted answer. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is not correct

Please update it to

```
//div[@class="mdif"]//li/b/following-sibling::text()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ganesh Pandhere, for your answer. It works.